# Probability of choosing 3 numbers from a set

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am given a set $$A=(1,2...,8)$$ and I need to choose 3 numbers from set $A$ without replacement then what would be probability that minimum number is $3$ and maximum is $6$ ? Firstly I chose both $3,6$ and then one of the number from $(4,5)$ or first from $(4,5)$ and then $3,6$ or one at a time
$$P(E)= \frac{1}{^8C_2}.\frac{^2C_1}{^6C_1} + \frac{^2C_1}{^8C_1}.\frac{1}{^7C_2} + \frac{1}{8}.\frac{1}{7}.\frac{2}{6}$$ but I think my answer may not be correct , how to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{8}{3}$ equally likely ways to choose $3$ numbers from the $8$. Of these choices, $2$ are "favourable," namely $3,4,6$ and $3,5,6$. So the probability is $\frac{2}{\binom{8}{3}}$.

Comment: Interestingly answer given in the text book is 1/5

Comment: Check the wording of the problem then.  Are there any other phrases such as "given that such and such is true"?

Comment: The wording is quite clear, so it is not a matter of interpretation.

Comment: I was referring to the possibility of a transcription error by the OP @AndréNicolas or perhaps missing information (such as if the numbers are not uniformally distributed)

Comment: My comment was about the book's answer of $1/5$.

Comment: Even changing the 'and' to 'or' won't result in a fifth.

Answer (score 2):

### Just Count:

The number of ways to choose $3$ out of $8$ values is $\dbinom83=\color{red}{56}$.

There are $\color{red}{2}$ ways to choose them with $3$ being the smallest and $6$ being the largest:

- $3,4,6$
- $3,5,6$

Hence the probability is $\color{red}{\dfrac{2}{56}}$.

Comment: ${8\choose 3}=56$.

Comment: @paw88789: Ooops, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting as "minimum number is 3" meaning, no number smaller than 3 appears, and "maximum number is 6" meaning, no number larger than 6 appears (allowing 456 and 345 as allowable answers as well)

You have the option of approaching this via a combinations argument and you also have the option of approaching this via a permutations argument.  In either scenario, we want to count the number of ways of choosing three numbers that satisfy the conditions requested and divide by the number of ways of choosing three numbers with no restriction.

Since there are four numbers available to choose from if we try to satisfy the condition that the smallest number is 3 and the largest number is 6:

$P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|}=\frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}{8\cdot 7\cdot 6} = \frac{1}{14}$

Comment: You must have $3,6$ in the desired selections...

Comment: Hmm but 1/14 is not the answer

Comment: Then my interpretation of the condition "maximum" is flawed.  I was allowing 456 as a sequence in E, as in 3 is a lower bound and 6 is an upper bound.  If you require that 3 *must* appear in the sequence and 6 *must* appear in the sequence, then as Andre points out, there are exactly two possible selections (disregarding order)